# Sum of a Complex number Z with its Conjugate equals to zero. Conclusion?

Tags: complex-numbers

I saw an MCQ in a book that asks that sum of a complex number $Z$ with its Conjugate equals to zero if and only if Im$(Z)=0$. But my brain cannot absorb this answer. Because their sum equals to 2Re$(Z)$, therefore Re$(Z)$ must be zero. Isn't it?

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: Seems to me the same thing as you said.

Comment: Can you please recommend me an Objective MCQs book for an undergrad level? I observed a lot of errors and misconceptions in the book I'm studying so I want to leave that book.

Comment: Try *Complex Analysis* by Theodore W. Gamelin, or the book by Bak and Newman.

Answer (score 2):

Considering: $a=Re \ z$ and $b=Im \ z$
$$z+z^*=(a+i \ b)+(a-i \ b)=2a$$

$$2 \ a=0$$
$$a=0$$

Answer (score 1):

I think there; in place of sum it must be difference:

Let $x=Re \ z$ and $y=Im \ z$
$$z-z^*=(x+i \ y)-(x-i \ y)=2i\ y =0$$

$$2 \ y=0$$
$$y=0$$